# Log starts/stops events from Audit System

Tags: aix, audit

Im hardening an AIX 7.1 box and i need to ensure that all starts/stops of "audit" system are logged on the AIX System.

Does anyone have an idea on how can i achive this?

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/security/audit/events you have:

```
* audit()
    AUD_It = printf "cmd: %d arg: %d"
```

In /etc/security/audit/config add:

```
...
classes:
    others = AUD_It
...
users:
    root = others
    user = others
...
```

When you run the command:

```
# audit start
# audit query
# audit shutdown
```

You will see:

```
# tail -f stream.out

event           login    status      time                     command                         wpar name
--------------- -------- ----------- ------------------------ ------------------------------- -------------------------
AUD_It          user     OK          Mon Aug 19 13:47:04 2013 audit
       cmd: 1 arg: 0
AUD_It          user     OK          Mon Aug 19 13:47:19 2013 audit
       cmd: 2 arg: 0
AUD_It          user     OK          Mon Aug 19 13:47:25 2013 audit
       cmd: 4 arg: 0
```

Where cmd values:

- audit start command to enable the audit subsystem. This will generate
  the AUD_It event with a value of 1
- audit query command to see which events and objects are audited. This will generate the AUD_It event with a value of 2
- audit shutdown command to deactivate the audit subsystem again. This will generate the AUD_It event with a value of 4

( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.security/doc/security/setting_up_auditing.htm)